# How to add advanced styling options to an object literal for a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, plugins

I am building a jQuery plugin and am attempting to make it customizable by accepting options...

***I am clarifying my question...

The following is a jQuery to do list plugin. I want each dynamically-created list item to receive the default properties in the object literal. However, I cannot seem to get this to work. Here is what I have so far. Any recommendations? Thanks!

```
HTML
   <div id='to-do-container'>
     <h1>My To-Do List</h1>
     <input type="text" placeholder="New item" />
     <button id="add">Add</button>
   </div>

   <ul id="mylist"></ul>

   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("li").newPost();
     });
   </script>
```

```
jQuery

(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.newPost = function( options ) {

    $(function() {
      $("#add").on("click", function() {
        var val = $("input").val();
        if(val !== '') {
         var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val);
         $(elem).append("<button class='rem'>X</button>");
         $("#mylist").append(elem);
         $("input").val("");
         $(".rem").on("click", function() {
          $(this).parent().remove();
         });
        }
      });
    });

   var settings = $.extend({
       color: "red",
       background: "yellow"
   }, options );

   return this.css({
       color: settings.color,
       background: settings.background
   });
  };
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: No reason it shouldn't merge all the properties in `options` object. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem.

Comment: @charlietfl I figured out how to add those properties but now have a new issue. See above...

Comment: @charlietfl I have a new question regarding jQuery plugins, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497022/how-to-enable-dynamically-created-elements-in-a-jquery-plugin-to-receive-default