# How to enable dynamically created elements in a jquery plugin to receive default properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, plugins

The following is a jQuery to do list plugin. Adding text and clicking add triggers a jQuery function to add a list item to the UL container. I want each list item to receive the default properties listed inside the extend method, as well as to be customizable by accepting options. This is what I have so far (see below). How can I configure the plugin so that the list items will receive properties and options? This is not currently working. Please help! Thanks so much!

```
HTML

   <div id='to-do-container'>
     <h1>My To-Do List</h1>
     <input type="text" placeholder="New item" />
     <button id="add">Add</button>
   </div>

   <ul id="mylist"></ul>

   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("li").newPost();
     });
   </script>
```

```
jQuery

(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.newPost = function( options ) {

    $(function() {
      $("#add").on("click", function() {
        var val = $("input").val();
        if(val !== '') {
         var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val);
         $(elem).append("<button class='rem'>X</button>");
         $("#mylist").append(elem);
         $("input").val("");
         $(".rem").on("click", function() {
          $(this).parent().remove();
         });
        }
      });
    });

   var settings = $.extend({
       color: "red",
       background: "yellow"
   }, options );

   return this.css({
       color: settings.color,
       background: settings.background
   });
  };
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: You need to initialize plugin for each new `<li>` when you create it. The initialization in page load will only work on any existing ones

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Move all the `$('#add').on ` to page load block and then try `var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val).newPost(options)`

Comment: Could you perhaps reconfigure my code and show me what that looks like? When you say move $('#add').on to the page load block, do you mean move that to the HTML side?

Comment: Inside the `$(document).ready(...` is what i mean. Note that `$(function(){` inside plugin is same as document.ready but the plugin won't get called until there are elements that need it and would get called too often for the add button

Comment: @charlietfl This sort of worked, thanks! I was able to get it to work with the $('#add').on... in the same page load block as the .newPost() method. However, I think what I am trying to do is set this up so that $('#add').on... is out of sight and the .newPost() method is the only thing between the script tags on the HTML page, like other plugins. How do I set it up like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191194/discussion-between-js-is-awesome18-and-charlietfl).